# SnowFlake - Dashboard Multiple Filter issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm creating a dashboard in SnowFlake with 2 filters as:

- Supplier (:supplier)
- Date (:c_date)

I would like to have a Dashboard as below:

Supplier | Selected_Date | Average_12M_Spend | Average_12M_Weight | Current_Spend | Current_Weight

The purpose is when I select a Supplier and Date from the Filters, the information in the dashboard will be changed accordingly.

However, there is an issue with my code as:

*Syntax error: unexpected '='. (line 4)
syntax error line 4 at position 78 unexpected ','.
syntax error line 4 at position 79 unexpected ''1900-01-01''.
syntax error line 5 at position 41 unexpected '('.
syntax error line 5 at position 47 unexpected ','.
syntax error line 5 at position 48 unexpected ''1900-01-01''.
syntax error line 5 at position 76 unexpected '+'.
syntax error line 5 at position 80 unexpected '='.
syntax error line 5 at position 95 unexpected ')'.
syntax error line 5 at position 97 unexpected ''1900-01-01''.
syntax error line 6 at position 34 unexpected ')'.
syntax error line 13 at position 85 unexpected '='.
syntax error line 13 at position 101 unexpected ','.
syntax error line 14 at position 4 unexpected 'and'.
syntax error line 14 at position 45 unexpected '('.
syntax error line 14 at position 66 unexpected '='.
syntax error line 14 at position 94 unexpected ')'. (line 4)*

My code is:

```
with c as(select SUPPLIERNAME, sum(PRICEEXCLUDINGGST) as CURRENT_SPEND,sum(CHARGEWEIGHT) as CURRENT_WEIGHT, to_varchar(INVOICEDATE,'YYYY') as YEAR, to_varchar(INVOICEDATE,'MM') as MONTH
from A
where SUPPLIERNAME = :supplier
and INVOICEDATE >= DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month,'1900-01-01', =:c_date),'1900-01-01')
and INVOICEDATE < DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month,'1900-01-01', DateAdd(month,+1,=:c_date)),'1900-01-01')
group by (SUPPLIERNAME,YEAR,MONTH))
select p.*, c.CURRENT_SPEND, c.CURRENT_WEIGHT, c.CURRENT_SPEND/p.AVERAGE_12M_SPEND as SPEND_VARIANCE, c.CURRENT_WEIGHT/p.AVERAGE_12M_WEIGHT as WEIGHT_VARIANCE
from
(select SUPPLIERNAME, round(avg(TOTAL_SPEND),2) as AVERAGE_12M_SPEND, round(avg(TOTAL_WEIGHT),2) as AVERAGE_12M_WEIGHT from 
    (select SUPPLIERNAME,sum(PRICEEXCLUDINGGST) as TOTAL_SPEND,sum(CHARGEWEIGHT) as TOTAL_WEIGHT, to_varchar(INVOICEDATE,'YYYY') as YEAR, to_varchar(INVOICEDATE,'MM') as MONTH
    from A
    where SUPPLIERNAME = :supplier 
    and INVOICEDATE >=DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month,'1900-01-01', DateAdd(month,-12,=:c_date)),'1900-01-01')
    and INVOICEDATE < DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month,'1900-01-01', =:c_date),'1900-01-01')
    group by (SUPPLIERNAME,YEAR,MONTH)
    order by (SUPPLIERNAME,YEAR,MONTH))
group by (SUPPLIERNAME)) p left join c on p.SUPPLIERNAME = c.SUPPLIERNAME
```

Can you please advise what should I fix my code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "=:c_date" instead of ":c_date". This is one error.

```
with c as(select SUPPLIERNAME, sum(PRICEEXCLUDINGGST) as CURRENT_SPEND,sum(CHARGEWEIGHT) as CURRENT_WEIGHT, to_varchar(INVOICEDATE,'YYYY') as YEAR, to_varchar(INVOICEDATE,'MM') as MONTH
from A
where SUPPLIERNAME = :supplier
and INVOICEDATE >= DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month,'1900-01-01', :c_date),'1900-01-01')
and INVOICEDATE < DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month,'1900-01-01', DateAdd(month,+1,:c_date)),'1900-01-01')
group by (SUPPLIERNAME,YEAR,MONTH))
select p.*, c.CURRENT_SPEND, c.CURRENT_WEIGHT, c.CURRENT_SPEND/p.AVERAGE_12M_SPEND as SPEND_VARIANCE, c.CURRENT_WEIGHT/p.AVERAGE_12M_WEIGHT as WEIGHT_VARIANCE
from
(select SUPPLIERNAME, round(avg(TOTAL_SPEND),2) as AVERAGE_12M_SPEND, round(avg(TOTAL_WEIGHT),2) as AVERAGE_12M_WEIGHT from 
    (select SUPPLIERNAME,sum(PRICEEXCLUDINGGST) as TOTAL_SPEND,sum(CHARGEWEIGHT) as TOTAL_WEIGHT, to_varchar(INVOICEDATE,'YYYY') as YEAR, to_varchar(INVOICEDATE,'MM') as MONTH
            from A
            where SUPPLIERNAME = :supplier 
            and INVOICEDATE >=DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month,'1900-01-01', DateAdd(month,-12,:c_date)),'1900-01-01')
            and INVOICEDATE < DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month,'1900-01-01', :c_date),'1900-01-01')
            group by (SUPPLIERNAME,YEAR,MONTH)
            order by (SUPPLIERNAME,YEAR,MONTH))
        group by (SUPPLIERNAME)) p left join c on p.SUPPLIERNAME = c.SUPPLIERNAME
```

Comment: Thanks but I've tried to remove the '=' and another error appears:

"No valid expression found for :c_date. Expecting "<expression> = :c_date" (line 4)"

Comment: I am not sure whether you can use the filter-variable everywhere in the SELECT. Let me check that.

Comment: Thanks for your support, please let me know if you can find a solution for my issue.